# Getting repeats when wrapping element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to achive the following markup for each present quote on my site.

```
<div class="quote-wrapper">
<div class="quote-brdr-blue"></div>
 <blockquote>
  ...
 </blockquote>
</div>
```

My current attempt is:

```
$('blockquote').each(function(){
    var quoteHeight = $('blockquote').height();
    $('blockquote').wrap('<div class="quote-wrapper" />');
    $('blockquote').before( '<div class="quote-brdr-blue" /></div>' );
    $('.quote-brdr-blue').css('height', quoteHeight - 14 );
});
```

But my code is wrapping the same blockquote multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` instead of `$('blockquote')` inside the `.each` function to work on the specific `blockquote`.

`$('blockquote')` selects all blockquote element and thus you are wrapping all the blockquote in each iteration resulting in repeated wrapping on all blockquotes.

By using `this` you will be working on the specific element inside the iterate.

```js
$('blockquote').each(function(){
    var quoteHeight = $(this).height();
    $(this).wrap('<div class="quote-wrapper" />');
    $(this).before( '<div class="quote-brdr-blue" style="height: ' + (quoteHeight - 14) + 'px;" /></div>' );
});
```

```css
.quote-brdr-blue { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote>Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data Test Data</blockquote>
<blockquote>Test Data Test Data</blockquote>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the same height for all .quote-brdr-blue Any idea?

Comment: @user2300867 same issue as `blockquote` where `$('.quote-brdr-blue')` selects all elements added before `blockquote` and the height is set to the last `blockquote` element height. See my updated answer where I set the style attribute of the `quote-brdr-blue`..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('blockquote').each(function(){
    var quoteHeight = $(this).height();
    $(this).wrap('<div class="quote-wrapper" />');
    $(this).before( '<div class="quote-brdr-blue" /></div>' );
    $(this).prev('.quote-brdr-blue').css('height', quoteHeight - 14 );
});
```